# Item extraction from a list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

I wrote a function to delete and extract an Item from a list following the usual algorithm for extraction, but while it scans the list it deletes all the items before the searched element.
I am probably missing some pointer being dereferenced but I can't really see where...

Thank you in advance for the help.
[Here](https://github.com/aleLoPrete/APA/blob/master/s258684_3/L7/E03/main.c)'s the full code.

```
//DATA STRUCTURE
 typedef struct{//EQUIPMENT
    int inUse;
    object **arrEquip;
}equip;

typedef struct{//PG
    char code[MAXL];
    char name[MAXL];
    char class[MAXL];
    equip equip_t;
    stats stats_t;
}pg;

typedef struct nodePg theNodePg, *link;
struct nodePg{ //NODE
    pg pg_t;
    link next;
};

typedef struct{//LIST WRAPPER
    link head;
    link tail;
    int nPg;
}tabPg;

int main(){
    tabPg tabPg_t;
    tabInv tabInv_t;
    int choice;

    tabPg_t.head = NULL;
    tabPg_t.nPg = 0;

    do{
        printMenu(&choice);
        runSelectedFun(&tabPg_t, &tabInv_t, choice);
    }while(choice != 0);
    return 0;
}

 void runSelectedFun(tabPg *tabPg_t, tabInv *tabInv_t, int choice){
//[...]
pgExtraction(&tabPg_t->head);
//[...]
}

void pgExtraction(link *head){//eliminarlo dalla lista effettivamente
    char toBeDeleted[MAXL];
    theNodePg deleted;
    int flag = 0;
    printf("\nInserisci il codice del personaggio da eliminare");
    scanf("%s", toBeDeleted);
    deleted = extraction(head, toBeDeleted, &flag);
    if(flag == 1){
        printf("\nPersonaggio %s eliminato con successo!", deleted.pg_t.code);
    }
    else printf("\nIl codice inserito non ha corrispondenze all'interno della lista PG!\n");

}

theNodePg extraction(link *head, char *code, int *flag){
    link *xp,t;
    theNodePg deletedPg = {0};

    for (xp = head; xp != NULL; xp = &(*xp)->next) {
        if (strcmp((*xp)->pg_t.code, code) == 0) {
            t = (*xp);
            *xp = (*xp)->next;//eliminazione
            deletedPg = *t;
            free(t);
            *flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return deletedPg;
}
```

Comment: `*xp = (*xp)->next;` That looks wrong. If the node `*xp` is the one being deleted then the operation should be to chain the **previous** node to the current next. Something like `(*prev)->next = (*xp)->next;`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am already implicitly doing it. Since the previous one points to the current one, if I make the current points to the next, the previous will points to the next too.